# Logging with Express Node JS

Tags: node.js, express

I want to know what are the option of logging with Express similar to what good is to HAPI. I tried Morgan but not sure how can I log response time and other response information.

Thanks in advance for help,
Devang Desai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom token in Morgan.

For example, if you wanna log the HTTP method, status code, response time, and process ID, you could use this

```
// Define a custom token 'pid'
morgan.token('pid', function (request, response) { return process.pid; });

// Do the logging
app.use(morgan(function (tokens, request, response) {
    var log = tokens['method'](request, response) + ' ';
    log += tokens['status'](request, response) + ' ';
    log += tokens['response-time'](request, response) + ' ms - PID: ' + tokens['pid'](request, response);
    return log;
}));
```